# How to create an eval command?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm creating a discord bot using discord-jda and I want to create an eval command that executes codes using the messages in the discord server, How to do that?

Comment: can you give an example of the input eval command which should be executed?

Answer (score 0):

To read message from chat you'll need an EventListener

```
public class Test implements EventListener {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(GenericEvent event){
    //First you check if this event is whatever event you're listening for

        if(event instanceof MessageReceivedEvent){
            //Do whatever
            //Note that you can cast that event here, since it 100% is a MessageReceivedEvent

            MessageReceivedEvent messageReceivedEvent = (MessageReceivedEvent) event;

            //Or to operate directly
            TextChannel channel = ((MessageReceivedEvent)event).getChannel();
         }
    }
}
```

you can find about that here https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/1)-Events

Then you can use basic java to process that evennt and execute whatever you want, after that if you want to send things back you'll need a reference to a `TextChannel` (MessageReceivedEvent has the `getChannel()` method which is handy) and you can use `sendMessage()` on that.

Note this is just a overview to get you in the right track. It's hard to give more specific information with just what you've asked, if you edit your answer with more info, I'll be happy to update it here as well.